# Microsoft Excel not graphing $x = y^{1/2}$

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics, data-analysis

The experiment was relating the period of one "bounce" when you hang a weight on a spring and let it bounce. I have this data here, one being mass and one being time.

The time is an average of 5 trials, each one being and average of 20 bounces, to minimize human error.

```
t

0.3049s
0.3982s
0.4838s
0.5572s
0.6219s
0.6804s
0.7362s
0.7811s
0.8328s
0.869s
```

The mass is the mass that was used in each trial (they aren't going up in exact differences because each weight has a slight difference, nothing is perfect in the real world)

```
m

50.59g
100.43g
150.25g
200.19g
250.89g
301.16g
351.28g
400.79g
450.43g
499.71g
```

My problem is that I need to find the relationship between them, I know [$m = \frac{k}{4\pi^2}\times T^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) so I can work out $k$ like that but we need to graph it. In this equation, $k$ is the spring constant, $m$ is the mass hanging on the spring and $T$ is the period.

I can assume that the relationship is a `sqrt` relation, not sure on that one. But it appears to be the reverse of a square. Should it be $\frac{1}{x^2}$ then?

Either way my problem is still present, I have tried $\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{1}{x^2}$, $\sqrt{x}$, $x^2$, none of them produce a straight line.

The problem for SU is that when I go to graph the data on Excel I set the y axis data (which is the weights) and then when I go to set the x axis (which is the time) it just replaces the y axis with what I want to be the x axis, this is only happening when I have the `sqrt` of $m$ as the y axis and I try to set the x axis as the time.

The problem of math/physics is that, am I even using the right thing? To get a straight line it would need to be $x = y^{1/2}$ right? I thought I was doing the right thing, it is what we were told to do. I'm just not getting anything that looks right.

Comment: I can guess that $m$ is the mass, $T$ is the period you have measured, and $k$ is the spring constant; what are the other variables? What is $\Pi$? What are you plotting as your $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @ColinMcFaul I have edited the question to include explanation of the variables. $\Pi$ was supposed to be $\pi$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

Answer (score 1):

The equation you present, $m = \frac{k}{4\Pi^2}\times T^2$ is of the form $y = \mathrm{slope}\times x + \mathrm{intercept}$ for a straight line. To put it in that form, you can make the identifications $m \mapsto x$, $T^2 \mapsto y$, $\frac{4\Pi}{k} \mapsto \mathrm{slope}$. Your equation is also predicting $\mathrm{intercept} = 0$. I'm using mass as the x-variable because that is the independent variable you are actually controlling in your experiment. Time is then the dependent variable, so it gets plotted as the y-variable. As I mentioned in my comment, I'm guessing that $k$ is the spring constant, and I don't know what $\Pi$ is. Those are important for the physical interpretation of the slope, but aren't that important for getting the fit correct.

I'm plotting mass as my x-variable, and $T^2$ as my time variable. I didn't try to actually fit that to a straight line, but I did plot a straight line with no y-intercept on the same plot. Eye-balling those together, the fit looks nearly perfect. I don't see any evidence of any deviation from the law you're trying to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Your balance plate weighed about 6-7 grams and you need to take this into account. In order to get a good relation, you need to add a constant to all the weights. This is not exactly right, because the center of mass also changes a little when you add weights, but it's the major effect. The only thing you need to do is drop the first point, where there is a 10-15% error due to the weight of the balance.

Comment: The base weight was the first one, 50.59g

Comment: @SmartLemon: It isn't quite--- there is a shift either in the mass or in the length --- I found that I had to add an offset to make it match the square-root law, although it is approximately correct.